# SQL getting a column to match multiple conditions in CASE

Tags: mysql

Presented with the following snippet of SQL:

```
CASE
    WHEN (YEAR('2018-12-31') - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT('2018-12-31', '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 30) THEN '>= 30 (inclusive)'
    WHEN (YEAR('2018-12-31') - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT('2018-12-31', '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 20) THEN '>= 20 (inclusive)'
    WHEN (YEAR('2018-12-31') - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT('2018-12-31', '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 10) THEN '>= 10 (inclusive)'
    ELSE '< 10'
END
```

(The full query is below, the snippet above is just to highlight the problem)

The above current results in exclusive matches:

```
 (30 <= date_diff) = '>= 30'
 (20 <= date_diff <= 30) = '>= 20'
 (10 <= date_diff <= 20) = '>= 10'
 (date_diff < 10) = '< 10'
```

But what I need is inclusive matches:

```
 (30 <= date_diff <= 0) = '>= 30'
 (20 <= date_diff <= 0) = '>= 20'
 (10 <= date_diff <= 0) = '>= 10'
 (date_diff < 10) = '< 10'
```

So -  if a record is older than 30 years, it must be categorized in in `>= 10`, `>= 20` as well as `>= 30`, and so on.

**FULL QUERY**

```
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS `RecordCount`, `ExistingPlanned`, `ResponsibleOrg`, `StartDateTCDR`, `EndDateTCDR`, `SpecificEndDate`, `ResponsibleOrgOut`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`EndDateTCDR` < '1001-01-01' AND `SpecificEndDate` = 0) THEN '2018-12-31'
            WHEN (`EndDateTCDR` < '1001-01-01' AND `SpecificEndDate` = 1) THEN '-'
            ELSE `EndDateTCDR`
        END) AS `EndDate`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`StartDateTCDR` < '1001-01-01') THEN '-'
            ELSE `StartDateTCDR`
        END) AS `StartDate`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`StartDateTCDR` < '1001-01-01') THEN '-'
            WHEN (`StartDateTCDR` > '1001-01-01' AND `EndDateTCDR` < '1001-01-01' AND `SpecificEndDate` = 1) THEN '-'
            WHEN (`StartDateTCDR` > '1001-01-01' AND `EndDateTCDR` < '1001-01-01' AND `SpecificEndDate` = 0) THEN (
                CASE
                    WHEN (YEAR('2018-12-31') - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT('2018-12-31', '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 30) THEN '>= 30 (inclusive)'
                    WHEN (YEAR('2018-12-31') - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT('2018-12-31', '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 20) THEN '>= 20 (inclusive)'
                    WHEN (YEAR('2018-12-31') - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT('2018-12-31', '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 10) THEN '>= 10 (inclusive)'
                    ELSE '< 10'
                END
            )
            WHEN (`StartDateTCDR` > '1001-01-01' AND `EndDateTCDR` > '1001-01-01') THEN (
                CASE
                    WHEN (YEAR(`EndDateTCDR`) - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT(`EndDateTCDR`, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 30) THEN '>= 30 (inclusive)'
                    WHEN (YEAR(`EndDateTCDR`) - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT(`EndDateTCDR`, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 20) THEN '>= 20 (inclusive)'
                    WHEN (YEAR(`EndDateTCDR`) - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT(`EndDateTCDR`, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 10) THEN '>= 10 (inclusive)'
                    ELSE '< 10'
                END
            )
        END) AS `TCDRLength`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`StartDateTCDR` < '1001-01-01') THEN '-'
            WHEN (`StartDateTCDR` > '1001-01-01' AND `EndDateTCDR` < '1001-01-01' AND `SpecificEndDate` = 1) THEN '-'
            WHEN (`StartDateTCDR` > '1001-01-01' AND `EndDateTCDR` < '1001-01-01' AND `SpecificEndDate` = 0) THEN (
                ROUND((DATEDIFF('2018-12-31', `StartDateTCDR`) / 365), 2)
            )
            WHEN (`StartDateTCDR` > '1001-01-01' AND `EndDateTCDR` > '1001-01-01') THEN (
                ROUND((DATEDIFF(`EndDateTCDR`, `StartDateTCDR`) / 365), 2)
            )
        END) AS `ActualLength`
    FROM `data_records`
    LEFT JOIN `RespOrgLUT`
        ON `ResponsibleOrgIn` = `ResponsibleOrg`
    GROUP BY `ExistingPlanned`, `ResponsibleOrg`, `StartDateTCDR`, `EndDateTCDR`, `SpecificEndDate`, `ResponsibleOrgOut`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`, `ActualLength`, `TCDRLength`
    ORDER BY `ResponsibleOrg` ASC, `RecordCount` DESC, `ResponsibleOrgOut` ASC, `ActualLength` DESC, `TCDRLength` DESC
    LIMIT 0, 2000
```

**EDIT 1**

Using the suggestion by @Barmar, my query now looks like this, resulting in an error: `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`, so I clearly implemented it wrong, so any further assistance will be appreciated.

```
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS `RecordCount`, `ExistingPlanned`, `ResponsibleOrg`, `StartDateTCDR`, `EndDateTCDR`, `SpecificEndDate`, `ResponsibleOrgOut`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`EndDateTCDR` < '1001-01-01' AND `SpecificEndDate` = 0) THEN '2018-12-31'
            WHEN (`EndDateTCDR` < '1001-01-01' AND `SpecificEndDate` = 1) THEN '-'
            ELSE `EndDateTCDR`
        END) AS `EndDate`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`StartDateTCDR` < '1001-01-01') THEN '-'
            ELSE `StartDateTCDR`
        END) AS `StartDate`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`StartDateTCDR` < '1001-01-01') THEN '-'
            WHEN (`StartDateTCDR` > '1001-01-01' AND `EndDateTCDR` < '1001-01-01' AND `SpecificEndDate` = 1) THEN '-'
            WHEN (`StartDateTCDR` > '1001-01-01' AND `EndDateTCDR` < '1001-01-01' AND `SpecificEndDate` = 0) THEN (
                CASE
                    WHEN (YEAR('2018-12-31') - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT('2018-12-31', '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 30) THEN '>= 30 (inclusive)'
                    WHEN (YEAR('2018-12-31') - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT('2018-12-31', '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 20) THEN '>= 20 (inclusive)'
                    WHEN (YEAR('2018-12-31') - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT('2018-12-31', '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 10) THEN '>= 10 (inclusive)'
                    ELSE '< 10'
                END
            )
            WHEN (`StartDateTCDR` > '1001-01-01' AND `EndDateTCDR` > '1001-01-01') THEN (
                CASE
                    WHEN (YEAR(`EndDateTCDR`) - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT(`EndDateTCDR`, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 30) THEN '>= 30 (inclusive)'
                    WHEN (YEAR(`EndDateTCDR`) - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT(`EndDateTCDR`, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 20) THEN '>= 20 (inclusive)'
                    WHEN (YEAR(`EndDateTCDR`) - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT(`EndDateTCDR`, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 10) THEN '>= 10 (inclusive)'
                    ELSE '< 10'
                END
            )
        END) AS `TCDRLength`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`StartDateTCDR` < '1001-01-01') THEN '-'
            WHEN (`StartDateTCDR` > '1001-01-01' AND `EndDateTCDR` < '1001-01-01' AND `SpecificEndDate` = 1) THEN '-'
            WHEN (`StartDateTCDR` > '1001-01-01' AND `EndDateTCDR` < '1001-01-01' AND `SpecificEndDate` = 0) THEN (
                ROUND((DATEDIFF('2018-12-31', `StartDateTCDR`) / 365), 2)
            )
            WHEN (`StartDateTCDR` > '1001-01-01' AND `EndDateTCDR` > '1001-01-01') THEN (
                ROUND((DATEDIFF(`EndDateTCDR`, `StartDateTCDR`) / 365), 2)
            )
        END) AS `ActualLength`
    FROM `data_records`
    LEFT JOIN `RespOrgLUT` ON `ResponsibleOrgIn` = `ResponsibleOrg`
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT `category`, COUNT(*)
        FROM `data_records` dr
        JOIN (
            SELECT '< 10' AS `category`
            UNION
            SELECT '>= 10'
            UNION
            SELECT '>= 20'
            UNION
            SELECT '>= 30'
        ) AS c
            ON (`category` = '>= 30' AND (YEAR('2018-12-31') - YEAR(`dr`.`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT('2018-12-31', '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`dr`.`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 30))
            OR (`category` = '>= 20' AND (YEAR('2018-12-31') - YEAR(`dr`.`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT('2018-12-31', '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`dr`.`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 20))
            OR (`category` = '>= 10' AND (YEAR('2018-12-31') - YEAR(`dr`.`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT('2018-12-31', '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`dr`.`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 10))
            OR (`category` = '< 10' AND (YEAR('2018-12-31') - YEAR(`dr`.`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT('2018-12-31', '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`dr`.`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) < 10))
    )
    GROUP BY `ExistingPlanned`, `ResponsibleOrg`, `StartDateTCDR`, `EndDateTCDR`, `SpecificEndDate`, `ResponsibleOrgOut`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`, `ActualLength`, `TCDRLength`
    ORDER BY `ResponsibleOrg` ASC, `RecordCount` DESC, `ResponsibleOrgOut` ASC, `ActualLength` DESC, `TCDRLength` DESC
    LIMIT 0, 2000
```

Comment: If a row is in multiple categories, you want to create multiple rows in the result for it, each with a different category?

Comment: Or you want to list all the categories on the same row, like `>=30, >=20, >=10`?

Comment: Let's say I have 4 rows. One with age 31 years, one with age 24 years, one with age 11 years, and one with age 7 years, I am expecting the count >= 30 to have 1 entry, count >= 20 to have 2 entries, count >= 10 to have 3 entries, and count < 10 to have 1 entry - so 4 rows should in this case result in 7 row results - So - as your initial comment indicates.

Comment: You can fix the error by putting an alias after the subquery in the last `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the solution was not necessary to be done with a single query where the processing was done on SQL side. I opted for a broader query that got all the data at one shot, then processed the result set with PHP to get to the results I need.

Answer (score 1):

Join your table with a subquery that returns all the categories, then check whether the row fits the category. Here's a simplification showing just that part of the query, I don't have time right now to fill in your entire query.

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*)
FROM ...
JOIN (
    SELECT '< 10' AS category
    UNION
    SELECT '>= 10'
    UNION
    SELECT '>= 20'
    UNION
    SELECT '>= 30'
) AS c ON (category = '>= 30' AND (YEAR('2018-12-31') - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT('2018-12-31', '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 30))
        OR (category = '>= 20' AND (YEAR('2018-12-31') - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT('2018-12-31', '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 20))
        OR (category = '>= 10' AND (YEAR('2018-12-31') - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT('2018-12-31', '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) >= 10))
        OR (category = '< 10' AND (YEAR('2018-12-31') - YEAR(`StartDateTCDR`) - (DATE_FORMAT('2018-12-31', '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`StartDateTCDR`, '%m%d')) < 10))
GROUP BY Category, `ExistingPlanned`, `ResponsibleOrg`, `StartDateTCDR`, `EndDateTCDR`, `SpecificEndDate`, `ResponsibleOrgOut`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`, `ActualLength`, `TCDRLength`
```

Another way to do it would be a `UNION` of 4 queries, which each test for the age in their `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: Thank you - I am trying your answer. I am getting `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias` error, even after adding an alias on the join. I will appreciate it if you can do the full query when you have a chance - not a very huge rush, thanks a lot! Editing my question now to contain my attempt that gives the error.

Comment: I am going to try the 4 UNIONs next. I am not getting the actual answer correct as you posted. Thanks again for your attempt.

Comment: The unions is probably the simpler way, I wish I'd thought of it before doing the join.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar. I am making progress with the unions. It looks like it will work, and I will accept  your answer as correct, because it did mention the unions. Perhaps just edit it to make the unions the "focused" answer? Thank you again!

Comment: You should post your union solution as an answer and accept that.

Comment: I actually managed to use a single query without unions, and processed the result with PHP to add the tallies. I tried to use the "preferred method" of the framework developer by doing this in SQL, but on his request that PHP may be better suited for what needs to be done, I did it that way. I will thus post the answer of what I did. Thank you for your assistance.